# Environment variables not showing up on Openshift ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, sinatra, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I've been playing around with Open Shift and tried to pass an environment variable. First, I set it with `rhc env set TEST=foo -a myApp`. Then I ensured it was there with `rhc env list -a myAPP`, and it was.

Nest, in my app, I put `Test variable = <%= ENV['TEST'] %>`, but nothing shows up after I deploy. Is there something I'm missing here? Running ruby 2.0 cartridge with Sinatra, fwiw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing a "stop" and "start" on your application (not a restart) and see if they show up, i believe the ruby cartridge just touches "tmp/restart.txt" in your rails application/passenger to restart it, which does not reload apache and pick up new environment variables (would probably do something similar with rack based applications that are not rails also)

```
rhc app <appname> stop
rhc app <appname> start
```

Comment: That did it! Strange that a restart wouldn't do this too. Thanks for you help!

Comment: It's crazy. I spent the better part of the day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

the document of rhc I've just check, it is now

```
rhc app-start <appname>
rhc app-stop <appname>
```